# Automatically coloring entries in toc if they contain only default images

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, color

#### Introduction

I am working on a document with many images named in it. 
These images get inserted into the .pdf if they are located at the folder I told LaTeX to look in.
If there is no such image it gets replaced with a default image. 
Now, these images appear to be in different sections.

#### Goal

Sometimes there are sections (and subsections, etc) that contain only default images.
I'd like to automatically color the names of these sections (subsections, etc), that are entirely empty, in the Table of Contents
with some sort of grey. The heading itself should not be changed.

#### Approaches and Problems

```
\documentclass[a4paper, hidelinks]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx, mwe, hyperref, xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft} %% ----- could be helpful here?

\newcommand\img[2][]{
\IfFileExists{#2}{
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 -5,#1]{#2}
    }
{
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0  -5, width=.4\textwidth]{example-image} %% the default image in this case
}
}

\newcommand{\defineavailablecolor}[2]{
\colorlet{available#1}{#2}
\expandafter\def\csname isavailable#1\endcsname{
    \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries\color{available#1}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{available#1}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\color{available#1}}
    \renewcommand{\cftparafont}{\color{available#1}}}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\isavailable}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\@nameuse  {isavailable#1}}}%
\makeatother

\defineavailablecolor{yes}{black}
\defineavailablecolor{no}{gray}


\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{First Section} %% ----------- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\subsection{First Subsection} %% ----- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\section{Second Section} %% ----------- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\subsection{Second Subsection} %% ----- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\isavailable{no}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-d}

\isavailable{no}
\section{Third Section} %% ---------- Textcolor in toc should becoma grey
\isavailable{no}
\subsection{Third Subsection} %% ---- Textcolor in toc should become grey
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-e}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-f}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to do something similar to this: [Customizing the table of contents with two colors in Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555572/customizing-the-table-of-contents-with-two-colors-in-latex). Though, I still have to mark the entries manually ...

Regarding this last point: Maybe one could include an if statement? It could test, whether all the images in the section (etc.) are available or not.
If this is not the case, color the toc entry. But I also don't know how to test for more than one image ...

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the full solution yet -- for some reason the ToC color is wrong if the next `\section` does not have a `\subsection` etc.

The solution uses `xcntperchap` to track the number of images per section, subsection and subsubsection. If this number is zero, the ToC color is changed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft} %% ----- could be helpful here?
\usepackage{xcntperchap}%

\usepackage{xpatch}%

\newcounter{totalsection}%
\newcounter{totalsubsection}%
\newcounter{totalsubsubsection}%

\newcounter{imagecntr}[section]

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsection}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{subsection}{totalsubsection}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{subsubsection}{totalsubsubsection}

\RegisterCounters{section}{imagecntr}%
\RegisterCounters{subsection}{imagecntr}%
\RegisterCounters{subsubsection}{imagecntr}%

\DeclareRobustCommand{\changetocpagenumberfonts}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftsecpagefont{\bfseries\color{\toccolor}}%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftsubsecpagefont{\bfseries\color{\toccolor}}%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\bfseries\color{\toccolor}}%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftparapagefont{\bfseries\color{\toccolor}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \gdef\toccolor{availableyes}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
    \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \ifnum\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\number\value{total#1}]{#1}{imagecntr} > 0\relax
    \gdef\toccolor{availableno}%
    \fi%
    \changetocpagenumberfonts%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    \fi
    \@tempskipa #5\relax
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
        \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
      \endgroup
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \texorpdfstring{%
          \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\color{\toccolor}%
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
          \fi
          #7}{#7}%
      }%
    \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
        \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
          \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \texorpdfstring{%
          \protect\color{\toccolor}%
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#7}}{#7}%
          \fi
        }}%
    \fi
    \@xsect{#5}}
  \makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\img[2][]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}{%
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 -5,#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \stepcounter{imagecntr}%
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0  -5, width=.4\textwidth]{example-image} %% the default image in this case
  }%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \gdef\toccolor{availableyes}%
}


\newcommand{\defineavailablecolor}[2]{%
  \colorlet{available#1}{#2}%
}

\defineavailablecolor{yes}{black}
\defineavailablecolor{no}{gray}


\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{First Section} %% ----------- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\subsection{First Subsection} %% ----- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\section{Second Section} %% ----------- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\subsection{Second Subsection} %% ----- Textcolor in toc should stay black
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-d}

\section{Third Section} %% ---------- Textcolor in toc should becoma grey
\subsection{Third Subsection} %% ---- Textcolor in toc should become grey
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-e}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-f}

\section{Fourth section}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{ente.jpg}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\img[scale=0.3]{ente.jpg}

\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\img[scale=0.3]{ente.jpg}

\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\img[scale=0.3]{ente.jpg}

\section{And again some section with a default image}
\img[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-e}


\end{document}
```

[image]